# Serving IBM Worklight direct updates through a cdn

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cdn

Just wondering if there is any documentation/guidance to hosting the zip file downloaded during a direct update on a cdn. This is hinted at in section 6.1 of this document, but not really expanded:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/Scalability_and_Hardware_Sizing.pdf

Also, we're using WL 5.0.6.20131030-1441 - is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

We have APAR PI06287 which is part of Fix list for 5.0.6
Please check below links:

PI06287: AKAMAI CDN IS NOT SUPPORTED BY DIRECT UPDATE

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038650

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24036825

Is this what you are looking for?
Thanks,

D.J. Kim

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide any more details of this fix? I can't seem to find any. Is there also any information on how to go about what's needed to be done on the worklight side to use a cdn?

Comment: The CDN is not currently documented.
However, Direct Update through CDN is supported,
but requires workaround to be implemented due to a limitation
in the current release of Worklight.
I cannot post further here.
Soon, we will release DCF for this issue.
Please wait for a while.
Thanks,